Hidden resource limit in YouTube API?
I wish to use the YouTube API to retrieve video ids and their related categories, for statistical analysis.
I have an Account, an API key and a standard quota of 10,000 units per day. My Python script makes search requests that return 50 video ids at a time. I do this in batch mode and I impose a 30-second sleep between requests to avoid overloading the server. The queries execute with return status code 200 and I can see my quota being duly decremented.
Yet whatever I try, I can only retrieve exactly 600 ids per script execution and no more. Is there some other limit at work here? (IP address limit, ...)
I tried various forms of throttling, and checking for HTTP return code 429 in order to adjust my request rate, but this status code was never detected. It cannot be a pagination error because I do not paginate - I merely read (and write to file) the retrieved video ids.

What YouTube API endpoints do you reach? Some are more expensives than others.

Search Endpoint:
URL: BASE_URL + "search"
Parameters: key, part, maxResults, order, type, pageToken
Videos Endpoint:
URL: BASE_URL + "videos"
Parameters: key, part, id
and BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/"
